# What is the authorisation that allows someone to query their calendar via Google Assistant?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I am on Google Worspace Basic, having grandfathered from Google Apps 15 years ago. I am the administrator of the few domains that date from there.

Today I asked my Google Home mini what was my agenda for tomorrow (I hardly use Google Assistant at all) and the answer was *"in order to use this feature you need to ask for permission from your administrator"* (more or less - translated from Franch).

I went to the admin console but did not find anything related to Google Home (or Assistant).

Where can I configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://admin.google.com
2. On the search box type "Google Home"
   The search result should include

   > Apps > Additional Google services > Settings for Search And Assistant > Google Assistant settings User access to Google Workspace data and services using Google Assistant
3. Open the most relevant result (see the above). From there you should able to turn no the service for your domain.